# Javascript generate 14 Numbers (with normal distribution, negative skew and positive skew)

Tags: distribution, skew

> I want generate 14 Numbers (with normal distribution, negative skew and positive skew) that Sum equal to 100. (In Javascript)
>
> Note1: numbers returned should fall between 0 and 100
>
> Note2: this is only normal distribution ... Not negative skew and positive skew

```js
function distNormal() {
 
 var fldCnt = 14;
 var _val = 100
 //fldCntNotGray = $(_elm).not('.grayField').length;
 //fldCntGray = fldCnt-fldCntNotGray;
 //if (fldCntNotGray != 0) fldCnt = fldCntNotGray;
 if (Math.abs(fldCnt)%2 === 0) {isOdd = false;} else {isOdd = true;}
 if (isOdd) {
  meadian = parseInt(fldCnt/2)+1;
 } else {
  meadian = parseInt(fldCnt/2);
 }
 var sum = 0;
 var sumGray = 0;
 var cntGray = 0;
 var PI = Math.PI;
 
 var normalPattern = '', plus, MaxMinMax, MinMaxMin, normalDistr, A, Amax, Amin, Smax, Smin, Mu, Sigma, xi, arrPattern;
 normRatio = parseFloat((_val/meadian)/(fldCnt-meadian)*1.0874);
 for (var i = 0; i < fldCnt; i++){
  if (i < meadian) {plus = 0;} else {plus = 1;}
  if (normalPattern !== '') {normalPattern += '|';}
  MaxMinMax = Math.abs(parseInt((fldCnt/2-i)*-1)+plus);
  MinMaxMin = Math.abs((MaxMinMax+Math.abs(MaxMinMax)-MaxMinMax)-meadian);
  normalDistr = toPrecision(MinMaxMin*normRatio,1);
  
  A = fldCnt;
  Amax = _val;
  Amin = 1;
  Smax = 15;
  Smin = 1;
  Mu = A/2;
  Sigma = Smax+((Smax-Smin)/(Amax-Amin))*(A-Amax);
  xi = 1/(Sigma*(2*PI)^0.5) * Math.exp(-((i-Mu)^2) / (2*Sigma^2));
  
  //normalDistr = Math.round(xi-A);
  //$("input#"+_fld+"-"+(i+1)).not('.grayField').val(normalDistr);
  normalPattern += normalDistr;
  sum += parseFloat(normalDistr);
 }
 arrPattern = (normalPattern);
 alert(arrPattern);
}


function toPrecision(number,precision){
 var str = number.toString();
 var pos = str.indexOf(".");
 if(pos!=-1){
  var tempArr = str.split(".");
  if(tempArr[1].length<precision){
   tempArr[1] = parseInt(tempArr[1])*Math.pow(10,precision-parseInt(tempArr[1]))+"";
  } else{
   tempArr[1] = tempArr[1].slice(0,precision);
  }
  str = tempArr.join(".");
 } else {
  var tempSuffix = "";
  while(precision){
   tempSuffix += "0";
   precision--;      
  }
  str += "."+tempSuffix;
 }       
 return parseFloat(str);
}
```

> Note: Sum of my returned numbers Are NOT 100.... And distribution is Not accurate!